# Does Telekinetic Rebuke trigger on a save attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, reactions

It's been previously well-established that AoE spells and things that don't actually involve an attack roll don't trigger things like *Wrath of the Storm* because that reaction, specifically, calls for an attack:

> **Wrath of the Storm**: Also at 1st level, you can thunderously rebuke attackers. When a creature within 5 feet of you that you can see hits you with an attack, you can use your reaction to cause the creature to make a Dexterity saving throw.

The ***Telekinetic Rebuke*** under the *Gift of the Gem Dragon* feat is written a little differently:

> When you take damage from a creature that is within 10 feet of you, you can use your reaction to emanate telekinetic energy. The creature that dealt damage to you must make a Strength saving throw ....

No attack roll is specified, so AoE / save type assaults would seem to still qualify. But that seems to break the RAI sense of other such reactions that such assaults don't come from a specific attacker but from the environment, so the reactions don't trigger. But since the language is very intentionally different from the normal reaction of this sort, I'm thinking that, RAW and RAI, a *Fireball* or breath weapon or *Magic Missile* would in fact trigger *Telekinetic Rebuke* even if it wouldn't trigger the functionally similar *Wrath of the Storm*.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that an AoE might not trigger Telekinetic Rebuke? The wording seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Largely because other thematically similar "rebuke" reaction spells don't. The language seems like it should, but as a (relatively? totally?) unique example of such a thing in my by-no-means exhaustive experience, I mistrust my judgment call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The feature does what it says on the tin.

Telekinetic Rebuke states:

> When you take damage from a creature that is within 10 feet of you

The manner in which that damage is delivered is not specified, so it doesn’t matter. As long as it is from a creature and that creature is within 10 feet of you, it triggers Telekinetic Rebuke.

There is nothing in the feature description to indicate otherwise, and as you have observed, other reaction features do place restrictions on the way a creature damages you. If there were other restrictions, they would be written in the feature description.

Answer (score 0):

### You are right

There is no general rule or Sage Advice ruling for how **rebuke** features work, in contrast to such rules for other features like *teleportation* effects. In the absence of such a general rule or ruling to fill in missing feature text, each feature does exactly just what it says it does.

In this case, as [Thomas also explains](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/200557/75095), the feature text only demands that

> you take damage from a creature that is within 10 feet of you

That is the only condition. The means by which the creature deals this damage to you do not matter.